# How do I replace this Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

So I was recently added to a new project at work and the Java code has about 10-15 Singleton classes that are used EVERYWHERE.  The purpose of these classes is to obtain data from a server (when the client application starts) and make that data accessible throughout the program so that service calls don't have to be made every time it's needed, which makes sense in my mind.

However, after reading numerous posts about how terrible Singletons are, due to tight coupling and being untestable, how would I go about replacing them?  I've been told about dependency injection, but do I REALLY want to keep passing around the same data to almost every object in the application?  Any suggestions are useful.

Comment: I would love to take a shot at this question but it's far too broad. The title implies you have a particular singleton in mind - can you post a specific example of one you'd like to replace, with some usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use dependency injection (DI) in such cases, but as you said you don't like it.

The next thing I can think of is FACADE pattern, create a ApplicationFacade class and DI it where needed. (or make it static if you realy don't like DI)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on each Singleton.  For example, can the Singleton be broken down into a few static functions?  Or can it be broken down into a few smaller classes.  Maybe it's only used in a small portion of the application; therefore, a smaller class refactored for use in that module.  I think, ultimately, it depends on the use of each Singleton.  If it makes your code simpler, more extendable, cleaner, etc., then keep it; if not, refactor.

EDIT: To add, what is the need to refactor?  Is the code simple, clean, and does it work?  If so, then just look to add features to the application.  Always look to add code/features, not modify existing code.  In the end you have to answer, is it extendable?

Comment: Most of these classes are used to access some sort of data that was obtained from the server.  For example, singleton A, on initialization, makes a service call to obtain some data.  This class now has 2-3 Collection objects that are accessed throughout the program (they are unmodifiable).  Does it make sense to have a Singleton so that classes of the program can use this data to perform it's necessary functions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Guice.  You define your constructors to take just the direct dependencies (no factories of factories to pass deep dependencies downwards), annotate each injectable constructor with `@inject` and then you create "Module" classes that define the implementations to use for any abstract classes or interfaces used in those constructors.

Guice will use reflection magic to find implementations based on the instructions in the module classes and instantiate your object graph.  It's even smart enough to automatically use no-arg constructors for dependencies that you didn't explicitly define in the modules without you explicitly telling it to.

You can let Guice get much more entwined into your architecture than that, but if all you want to avoid is a chain of factories for injecting dependencies, then a little Guice is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could design your classes is with explicit dependencies factored out. If a class uses a singleton:

```
class Client {
  public void Method() {
    SomeService.getInstance().doSomething();
  }
}
```

It's hiding that dependency inside. To pull it out, (1) take it on construction or (2) on the involved method, if it makes sense (showing option 2):

```
class Client {
  public void Method(SomeService service) {
    service.doSomething();
  }
}
```

This is the first step. Later, you could extract an interface from the singleton and use it. This is a slow process: refactor, retest, iterate...